# Should lambda decay to function pointer in templated code?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++11, function-pointers

I read somewhere that a lambda function should decay to function pointer if the capture list is empty. The only reference I can find now is [n3052](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3052.html). With g++ (4.5 & 4.6) it works as expected, unless the lambda is declared within template code.

For example the following code compiles:

```
void foo() {
    void (*f)(void) = []{};
}
```

But it doesn't compile anymore when templated (if `foo` is actually called elsewhere):

```
template<class T>
void foo() {
    void (*f)(void) = []{};
}
```

In the reference above, I don't see an explanation of this behaviour. Is this a temporary limitation of g++, and if not, is there a (technical) reason not to allow this?

Comment: Note that N3052, which you cite, was indeed incorporated into the C++0x FCD (N3092 5.1.2/6).  Visual C++ 2010 does not implement the conversion at all (unsurprising, since the language permitting it was incorporated into the standard so soon before VC++ was released).  I've submitted a bug report on Microsoft Connect concerning that (though I anticipate it won't be fixed until the next release of Visual C++):  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/572138/visual-c-2010-does-not-permit-conversion-of-captureless-lambda-to-function-pointer

Comment: Just as an FYI: None of the above code is supported in Intel C++ 11.1

Comment: Its already in GCCs bugtracker, though as of now unconfirmed: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45080

Comment: @James Noob question (also to questioner). Given that a function pointer capture list is empty for a collection of lambdas, can we store these in a container without using std::function (expensive for cases i've come across...)?

It's been two years sorry about that, just stumbled on this page and was curious...

Answer (score 4):

I can think of no reason that it would be specifically disallowed. I'm guessing that it's just a temporary limitation of g++.

I also tried a few other things:

```
template <class T>
void foo(void (*f)(void)) {}

foo<int>([]{});
```

That works.

```
typedef void (*fun)(void);

template <class T>
fun foo() { return []{}; } // error: Cannot convert.

foo<int>()();
```

That doesn't (but does if `foo` is not parameterized).

Note: I only tested in g++ 4.5.

Comment: Yes, in the first case the lambda is declared in a non-template portion of code (although it is used by a template function). The same problem happens when the lambda is declared inside a template class.